# Comparing Guid with string

Tags: c#, string, comparison, guid

I'm surprised that I couldn't find an answer to this either in Google or here on SO, but what is the best way to compare a `string` to `Guid` taking into consideration case, and, if appropriate, performance

```
const string sid = "XXXXX-...."; // This comes from a third party library
Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid(); // This comes from the db

if (gid.ToString().ToLower() == sid.ToLower())

if (gid == new Guid(sid))

// Something else?
```

**Update:**
To make this question more compelling, I changed `sid` to a `const`... and since you can't have a `Guid const` this is the real problem I am dealing with.

Comment: Why don't you profile it yourself?

Comment: Because I don't know if there's a "something else"

Comment: Do you *need* to compare them as strings? The best way to compare them is probably to compare them as `Guid` types (i.e. `gid == new Guid(sid);`) unless you're doing this millions of times in quick succession or something.

Comment: Where are the `Guid` and `string` coming from? Given the example (`gid = Guid.NewGuid(); sid = "..."`) the fastest solution (and it's almost 100% accurate) would just be `if (false)`.

Comment: @itsme86 Is that your answer or are you offering speculation?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Your comment is not helpful... I would even say smarta$$.

Comment: Is sid a static GUID or can it change? If it's static, I assume that instantiating it once as a guid then comparing would be the fastest. If sid constantly changed, casting to a string should be better than instantiating memory for a new object over and over again.

Comment: @SerjSagan Well, it depends on your definition of "best" in this context, doesn't it? That's why I said "probably". One line of easily-recognizable code goes a long way for maintenance.

Comment: @itsme86 that's a good point

Comment: @SerjSagan My comment was a bit tongue in cheek, but I my point was that knowing exactly where these values are coming from would add some critically needed context to this question. Simply comparing strings and Guids is probably not the most pressing performance concern, and if you can change the system to store both values as Guids you're probably going to be better off in the long run.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Point taken, see Update

Comment: For some reason it let me type it in and even compiled, but restarting visual studio showed it throwing, that was strange. Anyway, why do you need it const? Const only fills wherever you use it in with the literal of what you had it as. Can you not just have it as readonly (or static readonly, if that's the functionality you're going for)

Comment: Why do you _need_ a `const`?  Why would a `readonly Guid` not work for you?

Comment: What if this is the way it was coming through from a third party library?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't compare `Guid`s as strings, and don't create a new `Guid` from a string just to compare it to an existing `Guid`.

Performance aside, there is not a single standard format for representing a `Guid` as a string, so you run the risk of comparing incompatible formats, and you have to ignore case, either by configuring `String.Compare` to do so or converting each to lower case.

A much more idiomatic and performant way is to create a static, readonly `Guid` from the constant string value and do all comparisons using native Guid equality:

```
const string sid = "3f72497b-188f-4d3a-92a1-c7432cfae62a";
static readonly Guid guid = new Guid(sid);

void Main()
{
    Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid(); // As an example, say this comes from the db
        
    Measure(() => (gid.ToString().ToLower() == sid.ToLower()));
    // result: 563 ms
            
    Measure(() => (gid == new Guid(sid)));
    // result: 629 ms

    Measure(() => (gid == guid));
    // result: 10 ms

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void Measure<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    
    sw.Start();
    for(int i = 1;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        T result = func();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

So string comparison and creating a new `Guid` from the constant value are 50-60 times more expensive than comparing the `Guid` to a static, read-only `Guid` created from the constant value.

Comment: This is the ideal approach. Peformance concerns aside, store data as exactly what it's intended to be (`Guid`'s as `Guid`'s, etc.) and you're far less likely to run into problems.

Comment: You are getting less time because your are not measuring the instantiation time for "static readonly Guid guid = new Guid(sid);". If you take that in the calculation, you will get a time like your "Measure(() => (gid == new Guid(sid)));"

Comment: @FedericoCalvagna but the point is that the guid creation only needs to happen _one time_ in method 3, versus a million times in method 2. If you only need to compare the guids one time, then either method 2 or 3 would be appropriate.

Comment: Agree to that scenario.. but if we consider only the specific question of having a Guid as a string, and a Guid object, and you want to compare both, then only your first two measures are valid.

Answer (score -2):

Elaborating on D Stanley

```cs
const string sid = "3f72497b-188f-4d3a-92a1-c7432cfae62a";
static readonly Guid guid = new Guid(sid);

static void Main()
{
    Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid(); // As an example, say this comes from the db

    Measure(() => (gid.ToString().ToLower() == sid.ToLower()));
    // result: 177 ms
    Measure(() => (gid == new Guid(sid)));
    // result: 113 ms
    Measure(() => (gid == guid));
    // result: 6 ms
    Measure(() => (gid == Guid.Parse(sid)));
    // result: 114 ms
    Measure(() => (gid.Equals(sid)));
    // result: 7 ms

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static void Measure<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        T result = func();
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

So if you can't store your guid in a constant, the built in Guid.Equals() is your preferred option.

Comment: Scratch the above, as we're missing the whole point that they need to be equal :)

Comment: This is not a valid answer, you have to do type casting before comparing.